# Trying to find a book from my childhood in UK, a collection of stories, one story a page, characters were all Rabbits

Tags: identification-request

I'm not sure if I'm asking in the right place, but hopefully someone can help.

I remember having this book as a child and it basically fell apart from so much use. It was a collection of stories, each story filled a page (maybe two), the pages were decorated with a border and the characters were almost always rabbits.

I've tried everywhere to find it but I can't remember the title or the cover (it fell off at some point and my memories are exclusively of it with no cover)

Edit: it's not Peter Rabbit. That much I'm certain of (as I still have that collection of books as well)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you remember anything more about this book - its physical size, approximate publication date (e.g. when were you a child?), plot details of any of the stories, was it originally written in English, how old children was it aimed at, ... ?

Comment: Hi, it was about A4 size and I remember it originally had a hardback cover. I had it around the mid-late 90s (I think I got it in 1996, possibly 1997). The rabbits tended to do quite human things, I remember them wearing clothes and I think there was one story where they were in a car. I was around 3/4 when I read it, it was aimed at improving reading and literacy I think. I have a feeling it may have been initially in American English? But I had it in English in the UK. Thanks!

Comment: My first thought was a re-issue of a Peter Rabbit collection, but the driving around in the car thing, makes that very unlikely...

Comment: It's definitely not Peter Rabbit, the style of drawings were different I remember and I still have my Peter Rabbit collection but not this one.

Comment: Could be a bit of along shot, but does this picture from "Romany Wood" ring any bells: https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/333196072421500851/

Comment: @AJM I can't say it does, the pictures of the rabbits I seem to remember were quite small and would border the page (or be at the bottom). Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this was resolved on Goodreads' group "[What's the name of that book???](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19997627-solved-childrens-book-from-the-mid-90s-read-in-the-uk-anthology-of-s)":

*More Five Minute Bunny Tales for Bedtime* by Geoffrey Cowan

I'm posting the answer here for the sake of potential future searches. If someone wants to add more detailed answer I'll gladly delete mine (if I'm allowed to).

Comment: Yes this is the book I was looking for (it's my Goodreads post) thank you for linking the two!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're looking for a Richard Scarry book such as *[The Bunny Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0375832246)*?

> A favorite Richard Scarry Little Golden Book is now in print in a gorgeous Big Golden Book edition! Long a popular Little Golden Book, the tale of a large bunny family wondering what their baby will grow up to be is one of Richard Scarry's best-and is now available in a deluxe hardcover edition. Perfect for springtime gift-giving!

Alternately, there are a lot of books in the [Busytown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busytown) setting although I don't know any that figures on a bunny family.

Comment: I don't believe this is it, it rings no bells at all :/

Comment: @moonCat93: Ah, sorry to hear. The stories are a bit longer than a page each too, so that doesn't match. I will keep thinking on it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me as I vaguely recall this story from my own childhood and I'd have read it early to mid 1980s.

After some googling I found it.  Its The Jeremy Mouse Book by Patricia Scarry.

I can't find a synopsis online but found this review on Amazon which fits with the beginning of the story:

> I received this book as a Christmas present in 1970. It is my absolute
>   favorite book. I can't get through too much of reading a bedtime story
>   to myself without falling asleep and dreaming of Deep Pond. It is a
>   perfect little children's story. I highly recommend it for small
>   Grandchildren. It teaches the lessons of empathy, compassion and sense
>   of community, especially for the little unexpected Mouse and his
>   little red convertible sports car. He was not the most popular animal
>   when he came speeding into town and blew his tire.

This is the cover of the book:

[image]

There's a copy Etsy (https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/658913242/the-jeremy-mouse-book-1969-first-edition) which has pictures of the inside, the goat in the shop I remember:

[image]

Comment: I can't say this is the book I'm looking for. It's the wrong size and I remember that specifically, it was like A4 rectangular size. Thanks though, may help someone else!

Comment: Sorry @mooncat93, my pc was glitching out yesterday and this should have been posted to another question! Managed to post it to the correct question in the end.  I can leave this answer here or delete it as its not relevant  to your question